# Optimizing Related Table Query

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have a users table with user info and a related table which will show the related users to the current user.

To get the related users to user id '25' my query looks like

```
SELECT
  id
FROM users u
  INNER JOIN (SELECT
                primary_id,
                secondary_id
              FROM users_rel
              WHERE primary_id = '25'
                   OR secondary_id = '25') temp
    ON (u.id = temp.primary_id
         OR u.id = temp.secondary_id)
WHERE u.id != '25'
```

the issue here is that in the `users_rel` table the user id can either be on the primary side or on the secondary side. Don't tell me to change that because its already done for 6 million records so i can not change it. this query takes from 2 to 5 mins to execute with `4000` records in `user_rel` table and `629241` in `users` table.

```
    user_rel TABLE
.--------------------------------.
|    id         |  (VARCHAR,36 ) |   
|   primary_id  |  (VARCHAR,36)  |
|  secondary_id |  (VARCHAR,36)  |
|    del        |  (TINYINT,1)   |
|.______________________________.|
```

and index is defined as combination of `primary_id` and `secondary_id`

Comment: can you post how the schema of `users_rel` was designed? are the two columns declared as foreign key or are they have any index defined?

Comment: You can use `25 IN (\`primary_id\`, \`secondary_id\`)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> its already done for 6 million records so i can not change it

Grow a pair Hardcore - that you've already got a *relatively small* amount of data in the tables is no good reason for not fixing a bad design.

It would help if you posted the exact structure (i.e. the create table statements) for both tables and the explain plan.

Why are you using a sub query instead of just joining the table? Starting again gives you something you can begin to optimize:

```
SELECT u.id
FROM users u
INNER JOIN users_rel r
    ON 25 in (primary_id, secondary_id)
    AND (u.id = r.primary_id 
        OR u.id=r.secondary_id)
WHERE u.id != '25';
```

This should give the same result. Whether it's faster....we don't know.

> index is defined as combination of primary_id and secondary_id

Why? It's not going to help much with this query - you need 2 indexes one on primary_id one on secondary_id.